# Promise catch issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Try to use Promises in my application on node.js. But faced with a trouble.

Is it possible for `catch()` to get `applicationObject` (just created in `then()`)?

How to pass `applicationObject` into `catch()`?

Error can be evoked by any cases - either by forcing a throw everywhere in application scoped by `execute()` or by system error.

Code example:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create applicationObject (used a Singleton pattern)
    let applicationObject = Application.getInstance();
    resolve(applicationObject);
})
.then(applicationObject => {
    // Working with applicationObject
    applicationObject.dbModel.beginTransaction();
    applicationObject.execute();
    applicationObject.dbModel.commit();
})
.catch(error => {
    // In any error case try to make some actions with this object
    // including rollback db changes
    applicationObject.dbModel.rollback(); // How to get applicationObject?
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please give more information about where the error is occured. (`Application.getInstance()` or `applicationObject.execute()` or something?)

Comment: You first need to solve the scoping issue. `let applicationObject` defines it in a function, then you are trying to use it in another function (the one that you pass as callback to `catch`).

Comment: @kuroneko0441, updated question. Error can be evoked by any cases - either by forcing a throw or by system error.

Comment: I think the real question is - why are you using promises here? Your code appears to be synchronous and you can just use a `try...catch` to handle errors.

Comment: Well, assuming an exception from `Application.getInstance()` would be the cause for the rejection that `catch` handles, you definitely cannot access an `applicationObject` that doesn't exist…

Comment: Thanks, #Bergi! Great remark. I have already took it into account. This part of application has already been completed and has been sucessfully tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if it's a Singleton then you could simply just recall `Application.getInstance()` inside the catch, if it's implemented correctly then it should have no additional cost.

Alternatively, just create it outside the Promise e.g.

```
 let applicationObject = Application.getInstance();
 new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   ...
 })
 .catch(err => {
   // applicationObject is accessible
 })
```

Or if it *has* to be created by the Promise, then just create the var outside the Promise i.e.

```
let applicationObject = null;
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  applicationObject = Application.getInstance();
  ...
})
```

Comment: Hm, I forgot that singleton always returns the same object. Thanks James!!

Answer (score 1):

If the error occurs inside the library, there is no way to get `applicationObject` in `.catch()`. If you want to use `applicationObject` in `.catch()`, you should keep the object outside of `Promise`.

```
let applicationObject;

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    applicationObject = Application.getInstance();
    resolve(applicationObject);
})
.then(applicationObject => {
    applicationObject.dbModel.beginTransaction();
    applicationObject.execute();
    applicationObject.dbModel.commit();
})
.catch(error => {
    if (!applicationObject) {
      // In this case, the error occured while creating applicationObject, so you should not call application.dbModel or something.
      return;
    }

    // In this case applicationObject created successfully, and the error occured while executing dbModel issue.
    // You should call rollback or something here.
    applicationObject.dbModel.rollback();
    ...
}
```